# How to combine two attribute from a json to create json predicate with in clause in Java?

Tags: java, jsonpath, jayway

I have a json as below

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95,
               "version": 1
            },
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Reas",
                "title": "Sayings of the Decade",
                "price": 8.96,
               "version": 2
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99,
                "version": 1
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99,
                "version": 2
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99,
                "version": 3
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

Now i want to filter the json based on two attributes.

for example: **$.store.book[?((@.category,@.version) in [('fiction',2),('reference',1)])]**

But above predicate is not working. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Thanks much! It worked. Sorry for delay in responding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax you showed does not look correct. As far as I understand the JayWay implementation (yes, this comes down to the implementation details of the library), you sequentially need to combine filters using `&&` and `||` like this:

```
$.store.book[?(@.category=='fiction' && @.version=='1' || @.category=='reference' && @.version=='2')]
```

First, I tried to r create a combined filter using `in`, but this seems to select more values than you want:

```
$.store.book[?(@.category in  ['fiction','reference'] && @.version in  ['1','2'])]
```